# Kafka Connect MySQL - No suitable driver found

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use Kafkaconnect to connect to mySQL.
As per the logs, I found the mySQL driver and JDBC connector had been loaded. However, I got an error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/mytestdb"

connect-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=xx.xx.xx.xx:9092
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="kafkaconnect" password="password";

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000


consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="kafkaconnect" password="password";

plugin.path=/app/plugin
```

JDBCSourceConnector.properties

```
name=jdbc_source_mysql_01
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://172.22.10.24:3306/mytestdb
connection.user=mytest
connection.password=password
topic.prefix=mysql-01-
poll.interval.ms=3600000
table.whitelist=mytestdb.test1
mode=bulk
```

/app/plugin

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxxx  kafka   17263 Feb  2 16:04 common-utils-6.0.0.jar
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 xxxx kafka  275158 Feb  2 13:31 kafka-connect-jdbc-10.6.3.jar
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 xxxx kafka 5492352 Sep  6 15:13 mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0_Mod-all.jar
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 xxxx kafka 2480823 Feb  2 16:02 mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar
```

Logs

```
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,018] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:77)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,051] INFO Loading plugin from: /app/plugin/mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0_Mod-all.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:277)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,965] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/app/plugin/mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0_Mod-all.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:299)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,965] INFO Added plugin 'com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,966] INFO Added plugin 'com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,966] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,966] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,966] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.NoneConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:37,971] INFO Loading plugin from: /app/plugin/kafka-connect-jdbc-10.6.3.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:277)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,023] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/app/plugin/kafka-connect-jdbc-10.6.3.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:299)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,023] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,023] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,024] INFO Loading plugin from: /app/plugin/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:277)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,346] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/app/plugin/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:299)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,354] INFO Loading plugin from: /app/plugin/common-utils-6.0.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:277)
[2023-02-02 16:20:38,364] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/app/plugin/common-utils-6.0.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:299)
```

ERROR

```
[2023-02-02 16:21:05,889] ERROR [jdbc_source_mysql_01|worker] WorkerConnector{id=jdbc_source_mysql_01} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:192)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/mytestdb
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:59)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector.start(JdbcSourceConnector.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:184)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:209)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:348)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:331)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/mytestdb
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getConnection(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:250)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:80)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:52)
        ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting 'export CLASSPATH=/app/plugin/*', it can connect to mySQL.